# Input type text and background image

Tags: html, css, image

I started to code last week in php/html/css and for this reason I'm not an expert in web programming. My goal is this picture:

[image]

So, I will use this picture as background-image in a separate css file (naturally without the two "input text"), up to now no problem. My question is, started from this picture, how can insert the two input text "Inside" (I know is not the correct world but I don't know exactly which is, sorry for this) this picture? Which way should I follow?

Sorry again if the question format is not correct, but I a newbie of web programming.

Comment: you can use rgba(values) for background transparency with specified height and place the content.. without posting any code you tried sofar, its difficult to answer..

Comment: This question is either too broad, **opinion based or requires discussion** and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made you an example pen take a look at this [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Veojdm)
Good luck!

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="inputs">
    <input type="text" /><br />
    <input type="password" />
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-image: url(http://wallpapersrang.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/black-jumpman-logo-jordan-wallpaper-tumblr-backgrounds-cool.png);
  background-size: cover;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.inputs {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will work on this. Of course I'll study the css code.

Answer (score 0):

you can do such things in many ways using background image and opacity. anyways for you reference i am sharing quick implementation [here](https://jsbin.com/yawegiviqo/edit?html,output)